# Taking 2 clicks to set variable in v-tab with Vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using Vuetify and vuejs to create 3 tabs. I'm dynamically switching between tabs by binding to the `href` of a `v-tab`. I'm just changing the `speed` variable each time I click on a tab. For some reason the `speed` variable, lags behind by one click. So even though I click on the `expedited` tab the `speed` variable is still stuck on `standard` until I click again, and THEN it is set to `expedited` and the tab works like normal. Here is my code, and there are no errors..

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-container fill-height>
      <v-layout row wrap align-center>
        <v-flex xs8 class="mx-auto">
            <h1 class="display-1 mont bold fix-title-height pb-3">Shipping Settings</h1>
            <v-tabs icons-and-text centered color="purple darken-3" dark class="elevation-12">
              <v-tabs-slider color="green lighten-1"></v-tabs-slider>
              <v-tab :href="'#' + speed" @click="setStandard">
                <!--I think the idea here is just to just emit the name passing it to the component which
                then is customized for that speed-->
                Standard
              </v-tab>
              <v-tab :href="'#' + speed" @click="setExpedited">
                Expedited
              </v-tab>
              <v-tab :href="'#' + speed" @click="setPriority">
                Priority
              </v-tab>

              <v-tab-item id="standard">
                <standard_speed></standard_speed>
              </v-tab-item>

              <v-tab-item id="expedited">
                <v-card flat>
                  <v-card-text>expedited here</v-card-text>
                </v-card>
              </v-tab-item>

              <v-tab-item id="priority">
                <v-card flat>
                  <v-card-text>priority here</v-card-text>
                </v-card>
              </v-tab-item>

            </v-tabs>
         </v-flex> 
     </v-layout>
    </v-container>   
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import standard_speed from '../components/standard_speed.vue';

export default {
  data: function() {
    return {
      speed: "standard"
    };
  },
  components: {
    standard_speed
  },
  methods: {
    setStandard() {
      console.log("Is speed getting set? " + this.speed);
      this.speed = "standard";
    },
    setExpedited() {
      this.speed = "expedited"
    },
    setPriority() {
      this.speed = "priority"
    },    
  }
};
</script>

<style>


</style>
```

Any idea why my `speed` variable is not getting updated on the first click?

Comment: why do u need href for v-tab at all?

Comment: @Aldarund what would you suggest instead? I don't want to use routes.. I'm using dynamic components most places.. and would it fix my main issue?

Comment: i dont understand what the use of setting href to tabs at all. If you just remove href at all tabs will wokr fine. What else will not work for you without href in tabs?

Comment: Oh, so the tabs go to the correct component.. you either need a route, a component or simply divs with an id to show content

Comment: still dont get. https://codepen.io/aldarund/pen/PaRvOm?&editors=101 - here basic example. You can also set v-model for v-tabs if you want to know what tab clicked

Comment: ha!! Well now I'm confused.. I don't even know where I got the `href` idea from! I used `key` like in your example AND in the docs, and it works perfect.. thank you! If you want to get credit for the answer just post it and I'll accept! Thank you much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to set href for v-tab. Its not even listed as option in [vuetify api docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/tabs)
Basic example would be

```
<v-tabs
      v-model="active"
      color="cyan"
      dark
      slider-color="yellow"
    >
      <v-tab
        v-for="n in 3"
        :key="n"
        ripple
      >
        Item {{ n }}
      </v-tab>
      <v-tab-item
        v-for="n in 3"
        :key="n"
      >
        <v-card flat>
          <v-card-text>{{ text }}</v-card-text>
        </v-card>
      </v-tab-item>
    </v-tabs>
```